# what's the name of a solar day on other planets?

Tags: space, solar-system, planets

people refer to a solar day on Mars as- "sol".
are there any specific names for solar days on other planets, such as Jupiter or Venus for instance?
or either "sol" is just a name for a solar day on a planet, not specifically on Mars?

thank you

Comment: Please see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sol_(day_on_Mars) - It is a convention for Mars only.

Comment: Depends on what language is spoken on Jupiter and Venus. If they speak English, then the word is *day*. If they speak German, *Tag*. If they speak Latin, *dies*. If they speak French, *jour*. And so on.

Comment: @AlexP this is of course why NASA, mostly english speakers, call days on mars "sols", right?

Comment: @StarfishPrime: The question asks for "names for a day on other planets". As far as I know, NASA lives on Earth and has never even been on any other planet, not even for a city break. NASA admits that "sol" is a made-up word to refer to days on Mars, exactly because they don't know what the Martian word for a day is.

Comment: @AlexP "Mars" is also a made up word to refer to the name of the planet, because no-one know what the Martian word for "mars" is. Of course, by convention, everyone calls it "Mars" anyway, and there are no martians to oppose this naming convention.

Comment: @StarfishPrime: The native name of China is not China. The native name of Hungary is not Hungary. The native name of Japan is not Japan. The native name of Finland is not Finland. It is very common for cities, countries and planets to have names in foreign languages which are not derived from the native name; it is usually taken as a compliment, illustrating that the city, or country or planet is important for the foreigners. For example, the Hungarian name of Vienna is Bécs, and the Polish name of Italy is Włochy.

Comment: @AlexP that would be relevant if there was such a thing as a martian native. Turns out, there aren't any.

Comment: @StarfishPrime: Oh. Another dream shattered. Or maybe there aren't any . . . *yet*.

Answer (score 2):

The term is not dependent on the speaker's current location, so much as the speaker referring to a unit of time based off his native planet/system. So, if "sol" is being used by earth people on mars to refer to an earth day, it would still be sol elsewhere, too. I've always heard "Sol" used to refer to either our sun or our solar system . . . pretty much interchangeably. So, the term would make more sense to a Sol-based culture that was interstellar, but could just be used in the hopes of the culture eventually being interstellar and still using the vernacular they were developing in the present (a "groovy" or "bodacious" thought, but unlikely to actually succeed, as each generation does enough reinventing of the language that it is virtually unrecognizable after a few generations).

Comment: The usage in this answer is backwards - in Mars-centric operations, *days* are Earth days, and *sols* are Mars days.

Comment: @Cadence that makes less sense (why would the days on one planet of the system that was not the original home world of life [earth] carry the name of the solar system as its day-name?), in that case, the question is far too broad, though I'd suggest the alternate of something like Arean (from Ares) for a Martian solar day.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons why you might not come across any relevant neologisms is that the [rotation periods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_period) of most of the bodies in the solar system that you might actually *land* on is rather long... using "day" as a shorthand for our terrestrial convention of 24 hour days, Mercury has a 58 day period, Venus 115 days, The Moon 29 days, Europa 3 days, Ganymede 7 days, Callisto 16 days, Titan 16 days... you get the idea. Ceres goes the other way with a 9 hour day. Mars is something of an odd-one-out, as it has a day-length close enough to our days that it might warrant a special name to avoid confusion, especially when you're operating a mission remotely from another planet. For the rest though, there's no ambiguity so no-one has bothered coining a suitable term.

For storytelling purposes, I'd be inclined to use "day" as the period of the human circadian cycle (because unmodified humans work best if they stick to that sort of pattern) and some other suitable term for the rotational period. For the moons of saturn or jupiter (or indeed the earth), *month* is a reasonable term, especially given its [origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Month) referring to our moon's cycle. Obviously that doesn't work well for places like Mercury or Venus, but they're also not the sort of places you'd necessarily want to live, so using technical terms instead of human-friendly ones isn't a particularly big deal.